# asp.net bulleted list control - how to hide bullet points?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've searched Google and cannot find anyway to remove the bullet points from the bulleted list control. I only want a list with the text only no numbers, bullet points or letters. How can I do this?

If i cant do this is there an alternative to this perhaps another control i should look into? I need to be able to get the values so I'm binding data to this control.

Heres the html just in case-

```
<ItemTemplate>                                                                                                
   <asp:Table ID="comparator_tbl" runat="server" CssClass="plainTable">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ID="demographic_cell" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">
                <asp:BulletedList ID="demographicComparator_lst" runat="server">
                </asp:BulletedList>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="detail_cell" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left">
                <asp:BulletedList ID="comparator_lst" runat="server">
                </asp:BulletedList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: bullet list control is used to show items as a bulleted list. if you dont need bullets the you should use simple list control...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bullet list control is used to show items as a bulleted list. if you don't need bullets the you should use simple list control... I think you will have to resort to setting this with CSS since the BulletStyle property of the BulletedList doesn't support a blank style.

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" style="list-style-type:none;" >
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove in asp.net. You need to specify `CssClass` property for it with some style class and it should have following styles:

```
.bullet-list { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is realy easy to do using CSS:

```
#ID-Of-Your-List ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The bulleted list is finally rendered as `<UL><LI>...</LI>...</UL>` in the browser and you can use CSS to handle this.

You can set the nonbulleted style to the list like this:

If the id of the list is `#BulletLessList` set the CSS entry as

```
#BulletLessList ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

If you wish to set the same style in multiple lists, you can set the css class to all the lists and set the css as

```
.BulletLessList ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Bullet list control is used to show items as a bulleted list. if you don't need bullets the you should use simple list control... I think you will have to resort to setting this with CSS since the BulletStyle property of the BulletedList doesn't support a blank style.